# Печать в C#

Tags: c#, print

Нужно вывести на печать данные из datagridview, который, в свою очередь, получает данные из коллекции. Как осуществить? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной ситуацией? Способ формирования bitmap изображения не пойдет. 
В datagridview будет 4 столбца с данными типа string.

Comment: wpf или winforms?

Comment: используя winforms.

Comment: А чем не катит стандартный путь? Не в Bitmap, а в `e.Graphics`? Например, как тут: http://simpleprogrammingexamples.blogspot.de/2009/01/c-printing.html

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот способ!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашелся на сайте msdn.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWinFormPrintDataGridView-75864c45

Answer (score 1):

классический и правильный подход был бы использовать какой либо построитель отчетов, но если разовая нужда и нуден быстрый и простой подход то можно распечатать сам контрол, неплохо описано на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561174/printing-a-net-datagridview), и еще встречались примеры на кодепрожекте.

Comment: Ох, нет. Описанный там способ не совсем корректно работает, сами можете проверить.
Но я уже нашел решение на сайте mdsn.