# Печать DataGridVeiw

Tags: c#, datagridview

Нужна помощь. Как мне распечатать всю таблицу из DGV?
Я паршу информацию с бд таким образом:

```
private void LoadData()
    {

        string connectString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog= 'Rebel';username=root;password=";

        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectString);

        myConnection.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM `Товары`";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, myConnection);

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            data.Add(new string[4]);

            data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
            data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
            data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
            data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();

        myConnection.Close();

        foreach (string[] s in data)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
    }
```

После парса, мне нужно её распечатать, я нашёл в поиске про печать таблицы, но она не полная и искажается. Может есть какой експорт в Exel или Word? 
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Первый же индекс в гугле https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853746/how-to-print-values-from-a-datagridview-control

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. по какому запросу? По русскоязычным явно такое не находит

Comment: @yolosora не хочу показаться высокомерным(действительно не первый индекс), но вы(все равно) плохо [искали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204535/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-c) :)

Там же ссылка на [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWinFormPrintDataGridView-75864c45)
Да и вообще, кто будет искать информацию по программированию на русском языке(имею в виду сам поиск, не его результат)?

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. очевидно, человек не владеющий английским